# How can I get build/rebuild realtime output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vspackage, processstartinfo

I'm making Visual Studio package where I start devenv.exe and try to build other solution. I need to get building output in realtime, so user can see building progress/output, but I don't know how to do it and if it's even possible.

I tried such way :

```
            string rebuildLog = string.Empty;
            string logFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = @"devenv.exe";
            psi.Arguments = "\"" + config.DmsPath + "\"" + @" /rebuild" + " Release|x64 " +" /out " + logFileName;

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo = psi;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            process.Start();

            while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                MessageBox.Show(line); // just to see if it works. It should go to log form
            }

            
            rebuildLog = GetRebuildLog(logFileName);
```

And rebuildLog has output.

What can I try next?

Comment: I am not sure but may be you need - http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/dotnet/ which is automated build system and do what you are expecting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found answer.
devenv.exe doesn't write simple console output, so i had to change

psi.FileName = @"devenv.exe"; to psi.FileName = @"devenv.**com**"; and it worked.